# How to determine the location of a touch using view property

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, interface-builder

I'm trying to develop some simple game apps. For a Pong-styled game, I have a moving ball that stays in bounds and two paddles. I implemented code that moves paddle 1 so that it reflects the ball as expected.

When I tried to add the same behavior to the other paddle, I tried this:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject]; // Picks up the touch

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view]; // Gets coordinates 
// to help move the paddle on the X axis; Y axis is determined by the paddle,
// so it only moves along one axis


if ([touch view] == paddle2) {
    // move the second paddle 
    ...    
}

else {
    // move the first paddle   
    ...
}
```

However, any touches only move paddle1, indicating the condition is never activated. Based on the documentation, I thought that by sending the `[touch view]` message, the image view that was touched would return its own name. 
What am I doing wrong? Is a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use different views for the paddles, use one host view with different `CALayers` for drawing you objects.
You can move you paddles by assigning new origin to the layers.
The view should proces the following methods

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

to find out where you touched it.
Assuming you know the frames of you paddles you can decide whether you hit them with the touch or not.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @Davyd. It certainly looks like a more elegant way to implement the behavior I had in mind. I'll look at this more this weekend, when I have more time. For now, I found an easy workaround by replacing the "if" statement with 'if (CGRectContainsPoint([paddle2 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view]))'. It seems to correctly recognize touches, and move when touched.

Comment: Yep, this will work. If you have only few views you will not notice any difference in performance.